# Pass argument onClick to props.function() executed via refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm sorry this title might be a bit of a head-scratcher, I just can't quite think of how exactly to phrase my issue (open to any suggestions).

Basically there are 3 components: `parent`, `ChildA`, and `ChildB`

`Parent` renders both children, `ChildB` has a ref tag, `Parent` uses that ref tag to pass `ChildB`'s function to `ChildA`.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    <ChildA openChildB={() => this.childb.open()} />
    <ChildB ref={instance => { this.childb = instance; }} />
  }
}
```

Pretty basic.

The issue I am running into is that when `ChildA` executes that function it needs to pass an argument. I can't seem to figure out the correct way to do that.

I tried using a different syntax to pass the function down to `ChildA` - 
`<ChildA openChildB={this.childb.open} />`

but that results in an error, `Can't Read Property Of Undefined`.

How can I pass a variable through this function? 
Any help would be very appreciated!

Edit: I know I could pass the argument up to `Parent` and then from there place it in the function `() => this.childb.open(arg)` but for the sake of organization I would really prefer to handle that all within `ChildA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    <ChildA openChildB={(arg1) => this.childb.open(arg1)} />
    <ChildB ref={instance => { this.childb = instance; }} />
  }
}
```

And inside `ChildA` you should make sure to pass the relevant argument when you call the `this.props.openChildB`:

```
function handleOpenOnB() {
    // This is an example, you should use the relevant value you want to pass to the openChildB function
    this.props.openChildB(this.state.val);
}
```